# Best way to pass a SurfaceView to android.media.MediaPlayer

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I'm writing an app that consumes media (audio/video) and that allows users to reply and/or post new media.

My question relates to the SurfaceView used to display the videos.  This SurfaceView object is shared between the MediaRecorder (recording a video) and the MediaPlayer (consuming/playing the video).

The MediaPlayer is located on its own Service, which runs on its own thread, as per the NPR example: [PlaybackService.java](https://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/PlaybackService.java)

Since the NPR example doesn't involve video, I was not sure about how to make the MediaPlayer on the Service aware of the SurfaceView in the UI.  I ended up using a static variable to solve this issue:

```
// MyFragmentClass.java

// CameraPreview is the sample class shown int he media section
// of the Android Developer site:
// http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#camera-preview
private static CameraPreview sCameraPreview;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    CameraPreview cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity());
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.video_preview);
    preview.addView(cameraPreview);
    setCameraPreview(cameraPreview);  // a static setter. 

    // Other classes are initialized afterwards, not relevant to this question...
}

public static CameraPreview getCameraPreview() {
    return sCameraPreview;
}

public static void setCameraPreview(CameraPreview cameraPreview) {
    sCameraPreview = cameraPreview;
}
```

Here's the method on the PlaybackService that takes care of preparing a video for playback:

```
// Params url and isVideo were extras on an Intent that triggers
// this method
synchronized private void prepareMediaPlayer(String url, boolean isVideo) {
    if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    } else {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
    }       

    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mediaUrl);
    if (isVideo) {
       // this is the important line
       mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(MyFragmentClass.getCameraPreview().getHolder());
       mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
    }
    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    sendIntent(STATUS_PLAYBACK_PREPARED);
}
```

It gets the job done, but I'm wondering if there's any better way to do it, specially because I'm debugging a random bug where the shared surface is not released, and it got me thinking:

1. Is there a better way to make my service class aware of the Service?
2. Is it a good approach to have a single SurfaceView for both Recording and Playback?

Thanks!